# Partial search in Endeca Property

Tags: search, properties, endeca

I have created a endeca property Address with RecordSearch (with WildCard) enabled.

When I search '487 Saxony' word for the above property in pipeline I get results (Matching Records: 10).
But when searching '487 Saxo' or '487 Sax', I'm not getting any result (Matching Records: 0).

Anyone please tell me what changes need to be done to get the desired result when searching '487 Saxo' or ''487 Sax'?

Note : I'm using version 6.1.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you put * at the end while searching?

Comment: Do we need to search with *, because in code we have to append this value.

Comment: there are two option, either append from front-end or append in code. Most of the implementation done from java script to append wild card chars

Comment: Thanks for your reply